# I am beginner for C-sharp.I was just learning how to write simple instruction for program

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-2.0

## [image]

This is the instruction and error message I received.

I just tried to write a line which possess two slace mark.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes used to denote character literals. More than one character is a string literal.So given data should be placed inside double quotes instead of single quotes.
And to display a string with escape characters/line breaks, have to add '@' symbol in front of a string.This marks the string as a verbatim string literal.

[Find updated code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGfg4.png)